# Problems with Keys in Hash

Tags: perl, file, hash, key

I've encountered a very strange problem after moving my script from a Windows machine to a Unix System.
I've written the READIN sub and tested it with success on Windows with Perl 5.16.3 but it won't work under Unix with Perl 5.14.2

```
sub READIN
{
my (%tmp, $val, $key);
open (DAT, "$_[0]")or die "Thou shalt not open this file, so I generated an error: $! \n";
while (<DAT>)
    {
    chomp;
    ($val, $key) = split (/;/);
    #print "Value -> $val - Key_for_Hash -> $key\n"; *#DBG - Works!*

    $tmp{$key} = exists $tmp{$key}? "$val" : $val;

    #print "ValueH -> $tmp{$key} - Key_for_HashH -> $key\n"; *#DBG - Works!*

    #print "KeyH-> $key - ValueH -> $tmp{$key}\n"; *#DBG - doesn't work, cuts of everything before " - ValueH....."*

    #print "Value2 -> $val - Key_for_Hash2 -> $key\n\n";*#DBG - Works!*

    }
close DAT or die "Filehandle is grumpy today and dislikes your Idea to be closed as of $\n";
return %tmp;
}
```

The output I get with Data::Dumper ist this:

```
    $VAR1 = {
' => '18.15.7.1.39.',
' => '19.15.7.1.39.',
' => '19.15.9.1.6.1.',
' => '19.15.7.1.6.',
' => '19.15.1.',
' => '18.15.1.',
' => '18.15.7.1.36.',
' => '18.15.7.1.34.',
' => '18.15.7.1.1.',
' => '18.15.7.1.33.',
' => '18.1.9.0',
' => '19.15.7.1.36.',
' => '16.15.2.1.4.1',
' => '18.15.7.1.38.',
' => '19.15.9.1.13.',
' => '18.15.9.1.6.1.',
' => '16.1.9.0',
' => '19.15.7.1.33.',
' => '19.15.7.1.37.',
' => '19.1.9.0',
' => '19.15.9.1.3.',e
' => '19.15.7.1.4.',
' => '19.15.7.1.38.',
' => '19.15.7.1.34.',
          'radioid2e' => '19.15.7.1.1.',
' => '16.15.2.1.4.1',
' => '19.15.7.1.35.',
' => '18.15.7.1.35.'
        };
```

and last, this is the data I'm reading in from a file:

16.1.9.0;rid
16.15.2.1.4.1;kap
16.15.2.1.4.1;mod
18.1.9.0;rid2
18.15.7.1.35.;tdmkapt2
18.15.7.1.38.;tdmkapr2
18.15.7.1.34.;modt2
18.15.7.1.33.;modr2
18.15.9.1.6.1.;tdmkap2
18.15.7.1.36.;etht2
18.15.7.1.39.;ethr2
18.15.1.;rt2
18.15.7.1.1.;radioid2
19.1.9.0;rid2e
19.15.7.1.35.;tdmkapt2e
19.15.7.1.38.;tdmkapr2e
19.15.7.1.34.;modt2e
19.15.7.1.33.;modr2e
19.15.9.1.6.1.;tdmkap2e
19.15.7.1.36.;etht2e
19.15.7.1.39.;ethr2e
19.15.1.;rt2e
19.15.7.1.4.;um2e
19.15.7.1.37.;lm2e
19.15.9.1.3.;glokapam2e
19.15.9.1.13.;ethkapam2e
19.15.7.1.6.;acmcpm
19.15.7.1.1.;radioid2e

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Or is it a general problem on 5.14.6?

//EDIT:

This is the Data::Dumper output I'll get in Windows (Perl 5.16.3):

```
$VAR1 = {
      'rid2e' => '19.1.9.0',
      'rt2' => '18.15.1.',
      'ethkapam2e' => '19.15.9.1.13.',
      'etht2' => '18.15.7.1.36.',
      'etht2e' => '19.15.7.1.36.',
      'tdmkapt2e' => '19.15.7.1.35.',
      'tdmkapr2' => '18.15.7.1.38.',
      'tdmkapt2' => '18.15.7.1.35.',
      'ethr2' => '18.15.7.1.39.',
      'ethr2e' => '19.15.7.1.39.',
      'tdmkap2e' => '19.15.9.1.6.1.',
      'acmcpm' => '19.15.7.1.6.',
      'rt2e' => '19.15.1.',
      'modt2e' => '19.15.7.1.34.',
      'modr2e' => '19.15.7.1.33.',
      'um2e' => '19.15.7.1.4.',
      'radioid2' => '18.15.7.1.1.',
      'tdmkap2' => '18.15.9.1.6.1.',
      'rid' => '16.1.9.0',
      'modr2' => '18.15.7.1.33.',
      'glokapam2e' => '19.15.9.1.3.',
      'rid2' => '18.1.9.0',
      'kap' => '16.15.2.1.4.1',
      'tdmkapr2e' => '19.15.7.1.38.',
      'radioid2e' => '19.15.7.1.1.',
      'modt2' => '18.15.7.1.34.',
      'mod' => '16.15.2.1.4.1',
      'lm2e' => '19.15.7.1.37.'
    };
```

Comment: It isn't obvious what you're expecting how output should look like, can you explain it better?

Comment: I'm expecting the key's for the corresponding values should also be in the output like in this row `'radioid2e' => '19.15.7.1.1.',` only with different data of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have an `\r\n` line ending there. Instead of `chomp`, you might try using

```
s/[\r\n]+$//g;
```

This is a common problem when importing files from another OS, such as Windows. The chomp command removes the native newline character (contained in the variable `$/`) from the end of line. In linux, this would be `\n`, but in Windows it is `\r\n`. So in linux, you read a line up to `\n`, remove the `\n`, and the `\r` resets the cursor to the start of line, so that the beginning of the line is overwritten.

In reality, this is mainly a visual problem (besides having the junk `\r` character in the string). If you add

```
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
```

to your code, you will see the `\r` character printed out in plain text, like this:

```
"ethr2\r" => "18.15.7.1.39.",
```

You should also know the following:

- always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It will help you more than any other thing you might use in your code, and learning to use them is not that difficult.
- `$tmp{$key} = exists $tmp{$key}? "$val" : $val;` does nothing, because `"$val"` and `$val` are identical. If you have `use warnings` it will warn you if the key does not exist with the warning `Use of uninitialized value $val in string`
- Since it is unlikely that you want to split more than 2 times, you might as well use a limit on your split: `split /;/, $_, 2;`

Comment: does it make sense to change `$/`?

Comment: @mpapec There are various solutions to change to a hardcoded solution to suit the CRLF files, but I always find that the problem is that people's files vary, so that a hardcoded solution is not preferable.

Comment: Ahh, so in fact the rest of his code does work correctly, but the keys are invisible because printing the \r returns the cursor to the start of the line. Tricky.

Comment: This was exactly the problem, I wouldn't have found this in days... I've just corrected the read in data (as these are static "config" files) but could you please explain how I could exchange the chomp command with `s/[\r\n]+$//g;` ?

Comment: @user2982931 This is a common problem when importing files from another OS, such as Windows. The `chomp` command removes the native newline character (contained in the variable `$/`) from the end of line. In linux, this would be `\n`, but in Windows it is `\r\n`. So in linux, you read a line up to `\n`, remove the `\n`, and the `\r` resets the cursor to the start of line, so that the beginning of the line is overwritten.